# How to echo or print to test the if else condition in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple time-calculating program in ASP.NET where people enter an amount, an annual interest, and a payment per month.

I need to get the time in months to when the debt is paid of along with interest, and i want to test if the monthly payment amount is smaller than the monthly interest amount using an `if else` condition but it doesn't seem to be working. If I provide a monthly payment smaller than the monthly interest amount, then the program hangs.

My code:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        int BorrowAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtBorrow.Text);
        double InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(txtRate.Text);
        int MonthlyPay = Convert.ToInt32(txtMAmount.Text);

        double Rammount = BorrowAmount;
        
        double monthlyIntRate = InterestRate / 12;
        //LblNoMonths.Text = Convert.ToString(monthlyIntRate);
        //LblNoMonths.Text = Convert.ToString(monthlyIntRate);
        double firstmonthlyIntRateAmt = ((monthlyIntRate / 100) * Rammount);
        
        
        if (MonthlyPay >= firstmonthlyIntRateAmt)
        {
            int month = 0;
            while (Rammount >= MonthlyPay)
            {
                month++;
                double monthlyIntRateAmt = ((monthlyIntRate / 100) * Rammount);

                Rammount = Rammount - (MonthlyPay - monthlyIntRateAmt);

            }
            LblNoMonths.Text = Convert.ToString(month);
        }
        else
        {
           
            LblNoMonths.Text ="Monthly payment is less than the monthly interest rate!!";

        }
        

       
    }
}
```

The code inside else condition seems to have no effect:

```
LblNoMonths.Text =@"Monthly payment is less than the monthly interest rate!!";
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: That is what debugger in VS for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just press F9 on If Statement (Break Point) and start debugging. to go step forward just use F10 to follow code execution flow! ;) You can also use VS watch window to see exact amount inside each value ... nothing else would help you!

Answer (score 1):

For what you're telling us, it looks like your program hangs. I can't help you directly with your logic (because that depends on what calculus you want to perform), but at least I can point you out a couple of things to help fix the problem

The while condition is probably the place where your program hangs. Depending on the values set to the variables, you may never exit this loop. You have to be careful and redesign it in a way where there's an exit condition if the values don't make sense. If you're really getting stuck here for some specific values, a way to check for it is to either run the program in debug mode (and manually testing for an infinite loop), or you can easily do some Console.WriteLine statements inside the while loop with a counter, and checking the console window's output, that should give you the hint if the loop never exits.
The same thing goes for the else clause, write to the console debug output and see if the code's entering there or not, that should point you in the right direction. Anyway, this is to **identify** the problem, to fix it probably will take a change in your code logic (as i told you, specifying an exit condition in the while loop when something doesn't make sense from the business point of view)